# Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0xdeadbaad (code=1) error

Tags: android, andengine

i am on a game project in android with andengine like FruitNinja in which i am using to throw images from bottom to top 
project is working fine but giving error this sometimes
i used System.gc() but not helpful

Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0xdeadbaad (code=1)

my code is

```
private void throwHardware(final float pX, final float pY) {

    final FixtureDef boxFixtureDef = PhysicsFactory.createFixtureDef(0.1f,
            0.5f, 0.5f);
    boxFixtureDef.filter.categoryBits = 0x0002;
    boxFixtureDef.filter.maskBits = 0x0004;
    boxFixtureDef.filter.groupIndex = 2;
    Random rng = new Random();
    generated1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    r = rng.nextInt(8);
    Log.e(Integer.toString(r), "r");
    if (r == 0) {
        Hardware = new Sprite(pX, pY, java,
                this.getVertexBufferObjectManager());
        body = PhysicsFactory.createBoxBody(this.mPhysicsWorldg, Hardware,
                BodyType.DynamicBody, boxFixtureDef);
        mHardware[active] = new Sprite(pX, pY, java,
                this.getVertexBufferObjectManager()) {
            @Override
            public boolean onAreaTouched(TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent,
                    float X, float Y) {
                if (pSceneTouchEvent.isActionDown()) {

                    if (a == 0) {
                        score();
                        remove();
                        question();
                    } else {
                        remove();
                        wrong();
                        question();

                    }
                    return true;
                }
                return true;
            };
        };
    } else if (r == 1) {
        Hardware = new Sprite(pX, pY, facebook,
                this.getVertexBufferObjectManager());
        body = PhysicsFactory.createBoxBody(this.mPhysicsWorldg, Hardware,
                BodyType.DynamicBody, boxFixtureDef);

        mHardware[active] = new Sprite(pX, pY, this.facebook,
                this.getVertexBufferObjectManager()) {
            @Override
            public boolean onAreaTouched(TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent,
                    float X, float Y) {
                if (pSceneTouchEvent.isActionDown()) {
                    if (a == 1) {
                        score();
                        remove();
                        question();
                    } else {
                        remove();
                        wrong();
                        question();
                    }
                    return true;
                }
                return true;
            };
        };
    } else if (r == 2) {
        Hardware = new Sprite(pX, pY, android,
                this.getVertexBufferObjectManager());
        body = PhysicsFactory.createBoxBody(this.mPhysicsWorldg, Hardware,
                BodyType.DynamicBody, boxFixtureDef);
        mHardware[active] = new Sprite(pX, pY, android,
                this.getVertexBufferObjectManager()) {
            @Override
            public boolean onAreaTouched(TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent,
                    float X, float Y) {
                if (pSceneTouchEvent.isActionDown()) {
                    if (a == 2) {
                        score();
                        remove();
                        question();
                    } else {
                        remove();
                        wrong();
                        question();

                    }
                    return true;
                }
                return true;
            };
        };
    } else if (r == 3) {
        Hardware = new Sprite(pX, pY, usb,
                this.getVertexBufferObjectManager());
        body = PhysicsFactory.createBoxBody(this.mPhysicsWorldg, Hardware,
                BodyType.DynamicBody, boxFixtureDef);
        mHardware[active] = new Sprite(pX, pY, usb,
                this.getVertexBufferObjectManager()) {
            @Override
            public boolean onAreaTouched(TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent,
                    float X, float Y) {
                if (pSceneTouchEvent.isActionDown()) {
                    if (a == 3) {
                        score();
                        remove();
                        question();
                    } else {
                        remove();
                        wrong();
                        question();

                    }
                    return true;
                }
                return true;
            };
        };
    } else if (r == 4) {
        Hardware = new Sprite(pX, pY, google,
                this.getVertexBufferObjectManager());
        body = PhysicsFactory.createBoxBody(this.mPhysicsWorldg, Hardware,
                BodyType.DynamicBody, boxFixtureDef);
        mHardware[active] = new Sprite(pX, pY, google,
                this.getVertexBufferObjectManager()) {
            @Override
            public boolean onAreaTouched(TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent,
                    float X, float Y) {
                if (pSceneTouchEvent.isActionDown()) {
                    if (a == 4) {
                        score();
                        remove();
                        question();
                    } else {
                        remove();
                        question();
                        wrong();
                    }
                    return true;
                }
                return true;
            };
        };
    } else if (r == 5) {
        Hardware = new Sprite(pX, pY, ram,
                this.getVertexBufferObjectManager());
        body = PhysicsFactory.createBoxBody(this.mPhysicsWorldg, Hardware,
                BodyType.DynamicBody, boxFixtureDef);
        mHardware[active] = new Sprite(pX, pY, ram,
                this.getVertexBufferObjectManager()) {
            @Override
            public boolean onAreaTouched(TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent,
                    float X, float Y) {
                if (pSceneTouchEvent.isActionDown()) {
                    if (a == 5) {
                        score();
                        remove();
                        question();
                    } else {
                        remove();
                        question();
                        wrong();
                    }
                    return true;
                }
                return true;
            };
        };
    } else if (r == 6) {
        Hardware = new Sprite(pX, pY, cd,
                this.getVertexBufferObjectManager());
        body = PhysicsFactory.createBoxBody(this.mPhysicsWorldg, Hardware,
                BodyType.DynamicBody, boxFixtureDef);
        mHardware[active] = new Sprite(pX, pY, cd,
                this.getVertexBufferObjectManager()) {
            @Override
            public boolean onAreaTouched(TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent,
                    float X, float Y) {
                if (pSceneTouchEvent.isActionDown()) {
                    if (a == 6) {
                        score();
                        remove();
                        question();
                    } else {

                        remove();
                        wrong();
                        question();
                    }
                    return true;
                }
                return true;
            }

        };
    } else if (r == 7) {
        Hardware = new Sprite(pX, pY, samsung,
                this.getVertexBufferObjectManager());
        body = PhysicsFactory.createBoxBody(this.mPhysicsWorldg, Hardware,
                BodyType.DynamicBody, boxFixtureDef);
        mHardware[active] = new Sprite(pX, pY, samsung,
                this.getVertexBufferObjectManager()) {
            @Override
            public boolean onAreaTouched(TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent,
                    float X, float Y) {
                if (pSceneTouchEvent.isActionDown()) {
                    if (a == 7) {
                        score();
                        remove();
                        question();
                    } else {
                        remove();
                        wrong();
                        question();
                    }
                    return true;
                }
                return true;
            };
        };
    }

    mHardwareBody[active] = PhysicsFactory.createBoxBody(
            this.mPhysicsWorldg, mHardware[active], BodyType.DynamicBody,
            boxFixtureDef);

    scene.attachChild(mHardware[active]);

    this.mPhysicsWorldg.registerPhysicsConnector(new PhysicsConnector(
            mHardware[active], mHardwareBody[active], true, false));

    Vector2 velocity = Vector2Pool.obtain(-1, -16);
    body.setTransform(velocity, 85);
    mHardwareBody[active].setLinearVelocity(velocity);
    Vector2Pool.recycle(velocity);
    this.scene.registerTouchArea(mHardware[active]);

}
```

Comment: As per my suggestion you have to release each of your object perfectly   otherwise some linkage fire this kind of error.

Answer (score 4):

Something's corrupted or uninitialised. `0xdeadbaad` looks like one of those debugging/sentinel addresses like `0xdeadbeef` or `0xbaadf00d`.

Something you may want to look into is heap corruption. According to [the Wikipedia HexSpeak page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexspeak):

> `0xDEADBAAD` ("dead bad") is used by the Android libc abort() function when native heap corruption is detected.

There's not really enough information in your question to give specific guidanve for fixing such a problem, it may be worth contacting the AndEngine bods to see what they think, assuming it's something being caused by their code (or your code indirectly through theirs).

Comment: so how to over Come with this

Comment: @Raj, given the limited info you have in the question, there are about a ... billion different things that could be causing this. You need to narrow it down somewhat. Just dumping your whole class in the question doesn't really help that much. Try to narrow it down a bit, such as outputting all variables before using them with debug statements, for example.

Comment: If you solve this problem then properly put as answer so other users also can get some benefit from it.

Comment: the solution is that u shouldnot define new sprites at runtime this is due to increase in heap size strt giving this error