# How to use sox in Android

Tags: android, c, sox

Currently I am developing an android application where I need to add audio effects like bass,treble.So there is port available in android (https://github.com/Kyborg2011/SoxPlayer) .So I imported it and I ran the application but I am getting fatal error and the other thing is that How can I play a sample song using sox.

Comment: Thanks for the assumption, but we're not brain readers, nor do we see your screen. Would you mind minding to be as kind as to please gently include the full stack trace in your question? Please. Also show your attempts at playing a song, and we will be able to suggest what to do...

Comment: ok thanks for your reply.@ppeterka66..I am facing Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0xdeadbaad (code=1) when I ran the sample application got from github (https://github.com/Kyborg2011/SoxPlayer)

Comment: According to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16686161/fatal-signal-11-sigsegv-at-0xdeadbaad-code-1-error), 0xdeadbaad (->Dead, bad) is a "sentinel" address saying that something is uninitialized...