# Invalid heap address and fatal signal 11 while decoding json string into java object

Tags: java, android, json, arraylist, static

I am calling a static method updateHistory(String message) of class DrawingView from another class useActivity multiple times. The statement inside updateHistory method(**marked inside code section**) creates runtime exception as

```
A/libc(8006): @@@ ABORTING: LIBC: ARGUMENT IS INVALID HEAP ADDRESS IN dlfree addr=0x6552d4a8
A/libc(8006): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0xdeadbaad (code=1), thread 8015 (FinalizerDaemon)
```

**useActivity.java**

```
public class UseActivity extends Activity implements Observer {
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){...}
...
public void updateHistory{
...
for loop(10 times){
DrawingView.updateHistory(message); //called 10 times & message is a string changes every time
}
...
...
}//class ends
```

**DrawingView.java**

```
public class DrawingView extends View  implements OnTouchListener  {
public static  DrawingView my_View=null;

public DrawingView(Context context, AttributeSet attr) {
super(context);
my_View=this;
...
}

public static void updateHistory(String json){

Gson gson2=new Gson();

ArrayList<Pair<Path, Paint>> my_Paths=gson2.fromJson(json,new TypeToken<ArrayList<Pair<Path,Paint>>>(){}.getType());
//The above statement creates problem
...
}

}//class ends
```

How can i change that statement as gson2.fromJson creates new arraylist object every time the method called.

**NOTE**

My basic objective is to convert the json string(previously encoded from ArrayList of Path) into ArrayList of Paths and draw them over canvas.

Answer (score 0):

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16686161/fatal-signal-11-sigsegv-at-0xdeadbaad-code-1-error) it looks like your libc heap is corrupted; do you have any native libraries loaded and running?

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed this issue using `fromJson` method.
To avoid this error, change this part of code to someting like that:

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(str);

Location objLocation = new Location("");
objLocation.setLatitude(json.getDouble("mLatitude"));
objLocation.setLongitude(json.getDouble("mLongitude"));
objLocation.setTime(json.getLong("mTime"));
objLocation.setAccuracy( (float) 
json.getDouble("mAccuracy"));
objLocation.setAltitude( json.getDouble("mAltitude"));
objLocation.setBearing( (float) json.getDouble("mBearing"));
objLocation.setElapsedRealtimeNanos( json.getLong("mElapsedRealtimeNanos"));
objLocation.setSpeed( (float) json.getDouble("mSpeed"));
```